# How to order when update in zend

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

How can i order when update multi row in Zend ?

For example, when I updated my table as follows :

```
SET @pos = 0 ;
UPDATE table SET sort = ( SELECT @pos := @pos + 1 ) where status = 1 ORDER BY id ASC;
```

Comment: what you are trying to achieve??

Comment: I try to update name for each chapter of story. I need rename of all chapter when i delete one of my chapter